# How to delete an object when a certain action is performed?

Tags: java, actionlistener

I was trying to delete an `array` of `JCheckBox` when the action of a `JButton` is performed. But, assigning null into this array is showing error .

This is the code where I've used it...

```
static void chkbox(JPanel pnl)
{
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n= sc.nextInt();
    JCheckBox[] box= new JCheckBox[n];

    box[0].setSelected(true);
    box[5].setSelected(true);

    JButton btndlt = new JButton("Delete");
    pnl.add(btndlt);

    btndlt.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            box=null;
            chkbox(pnl);
        }
    });     
}
```

Would anyone plz help me to find a way out... Thanks in advance .

Comment: please post the error

Comment: Is it normal that your box variable is never added to the panel?

Comment: You can't assign to a local variable from inside an anonymous inner class. This method doesn't make much sense anyway (reading from System.in from a graphical UI?). But if your code was a bit more realistic, the array should be a field of the class, not a local variable.

Comment: @Merv no, that's not how is works. The variable is of course set to null immediately. And since the previously referenced object is not reachable anymore, the GC will collect it some time later.

Comment: @Merv that is wrong in so many ways. The original array will stay. You've just created a new one and placed it where the old one was

Comment: " local variable box defined in an enclosing scope must be or effectively final "  - this the error.

Comment: Here I have precised my main code to represent the actual problem, I was trying to put a list of data with checkbox , the problem I'm facing is updating the list after deleting some elements , as it should show the list with updated checkboxes but, it's still shows the old list... for this I want to dispose the old array of checkboxes .

Answer (score 2):

If there are no references to the object then the garbage collector will eventually collect it.

There is no single line you can write to simply "Delete the object" though you could replace the array called box with a new array called box essentially writing over the old object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete objects in Java.